Complex Audio Issues with Logitech Zone Vibe 125 on Debian Linux and Zoom Interaction
I am facing multiple issues with my Logitech Zone Vibe 125 headphones, which are connected via Bluetooth to my Debian Linux system. Each time I launch Zoom, I encounter no audio output. While I can sometimes manage this issue by switching output sources in Pulse Audio Volume Control, other times, only a system reboot resolves it.
Further, when Zoom is active, other applications like Spotify have muffled audio, and YouTube videos fail to load, sticking on the loading animation. These problems cease once Zoom is closed, and audio quality returns to normal.
I've also tried using the fallback device feature in Pulse Audio Volume Control by selecting different devices as the fallback. Currently, I have disabled all devices except for my headphones.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have any suggestions for a more permanent fix? Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.
System Information:
Laptop: ThinkPad T480
OS: Debian 12 Bookworm (64-bit)
Desktop Environment: GNOME 43.9 (Wayland)

Thank you for any help you can provide.

You have two different questions here.  I can answer one of them, but not the other.

@bk2204 Ok would be nice to get near to a solution for my problem
